# Integrate Trac+SVN with Doxygen

Tags: svn, trac, doxygen

I am aware of the Trac Doxygen plugin. It allows linking to the Doxygen docs from the Trac wiki.

I am looking for something that will help me automate the documentation. Since the project is huge, it is probably not possible to update the documentation on every commit especially  since Doxygen doesn't do incremental documentation builds. Instead, a nightly documentation build is probably more effective.

I would like to see the changes between documentation builds. One solution is putting the Doxygen output in the SVN repository, but then we'd be comparing HTML and not documentation, which would get unpleasant, I'd imagine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [buildbot](http://www.buildbot.net/) to build the documentation nightly and after each commit.  The built documentation is published to an internal server to be accessible to all developers.

In fact, it seems that someone has written a [buildbot command](http://buildbot.net/trac/ticket/356) for doxygen build steps.  Of course, you can use your own, favorite integration platform instead.

Answer (score 1):

As our trac server is a linux server we use a simple build script and a cron job. The config file for doxygen is in the repository.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is super old, but I have a script that automates doxygen jobs on subversion paths, adds the documentation back into subversion and backs everything up. It may help someone: http://flauk.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/svndoxy/